# How would I use rspec to test a method who's job is to post to a webhook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm using rspec to test my application and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to test this. The Slack::Notifier's job is to send a post request to a webhook. Once I call this method in Rspec, I don't know how to see the response. Also, is it possible to match the format of this text to an expected text somewhere?  My method is below. Thanks.

```
def notify
    offset = 14400 #UTC to EST
    notifier = Slack::Notifier.new Rails.application.secrets.slack_organization_name,       Rails.application.secrets.slack_token, channel: "##{Rails.application.secrets.slack_channel}",      username: Rails.application.secrets.slack_user_name
    notifier.ping(":white_check_mark: *USAGE SUMMARY for #{(Time.now - offset).to_formatted_s(:long) }*")
    count = 0
    current_time = Time.now.to_i
    live_response.each do |r|

    if r["properties"]["time"] > ((current_time - offset) - 60) #&& r["properties"]["$initial_referring_domain"] == "capture.com"
      notifier.ping("
        *Name:* #{r["properties"]["$name"]}
        *Event:* #{r["event"]}
        *Keywords:* #{r["properties"]["keywords"]}
        *Organization:* #{r["properties"]["organizationName"]}
        *Email:* #{r["properties"]["$email"]}
        *Time:* #{Time.at(r["properties"]["time"] + offset).utc.to_datetime.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)").to_formatted_s(:long_ordinal)}
        *More Data:* #{ANALYTICS_URL}#{r["properties"]["distinct_id"]}
        __________________________________________________
       ")
      count +=1
    end
  end

  notifier.ping("*There were #{count} events in this report.*")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Testing network communications (like API calls) is a tricky thing. Personally I would rely on programming by contract and testing in isolation - i.e. assume the external service is working fine and it responds positively for valid request.

Then you test your client code by checking that you are actually sending a valid request. For this stub the method where control exits your code into a library/system code. For example if you are making a HTTP GET request using a gem like `HTTParty`, then stub `HTTParty.get` i.e. `HTTParty.stub(:get)` and in that stub verify that correct parameters were sent.

On the other side of the spectrum you should also simulated both positive and negative responses from the web service and make sure your client code handles it in expected manner.

If you are making a real then you are introducing a lot of dependencies on your test : a test setup of external service, risk of network issues (timeout, n/w breakdown, etc) problems with external service and may be more.

If you yourself are writing that webservice too then test that one also in isolation, i.e by simulating valid and invalid inputs and making sure they are handled properly. This part is pretty much your controller specs or request specs.

Once again, this is my opinion. Suggestions to do this in a better way and constructive criticism on the shortcomings of this approach are definitely welcome.